# Catch HTTP requests (including ajax) from the client

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, browser

I would like to write code that can catch:

- (1) Clicking on links or changing the window.location programmaticly
- (2) The user changes the url via the location bar
- (3) AJAX requests

Is it even possible? How do I do that?

Comment: nothing, I am not sure it's even possible, I wish I knew where to start...

Comment: Are you/would you consider using a framework such as jQuery?

Comment: yes I can instrument code that includes the jquery library, but I can't count on the fact that the existing page is using jquery...they probably don't.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, thats a simple step. Just give the button an action which access the server via AJAX.
2. What do you mean exactly? Do you want to know where the user heading to when he do that over the location bar?
3. Do you want to track every AJAX request or your goal is to send them via AJAX?

Comment: 1. I need a way to found all those buttons 2. yes 3. track every AJAX request

Answer (score 0):

I don't get completely what you are trying to achieve and at what point you want to instrument the code. But in case this helps, this something that can be achieved through HTTP Proxy . On a network you can redirect the traffic trough a Proxy server where in you can have your plugged in modules that can scan the outgoing requests and take some action(action could be reporting to some other server). Of course you won't need to instrument anything here. Most of the internet firewalls peg on this I guess.

Comment: i dont want to do that, I instrument js code to the page right before the client get it, and the code that I am instrumenting is the code that should catch those stuff